# Response status code 400 when using python module Requests with Sitescout API

Tags: python, python-requests, http-error

I have a client id and client secret and am attempting to generate an auth token by following [Sitescout's api docs](http://www.sitescout.com/support/api/#client_credentials). I'm using python module Requests and am getting a 400 status code back, aka malformed request, but I can't seem to figure out why.

My code:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token"
headers = { 
            "Host": "api.sitescout.com",
            "Authorization": "Basic YmVldGhvdmVuOmxldG1laW4=",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": "41"
        }

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

response.status_code
```

That is the fake base64 Authorization header provided in the docs so this snippet returns a 401 error, aka unauthorized (I have my own auth of course).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Can you post the output from `response.text()`?

Comment: response.text = {"error":"invalid_request"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been resolved. I did not put `grant_type=client_credentials` which, when added, returns a 200.

The docs say "Optionally, you can add form parameter scope to indicate which scopes you are requesting access to; the scope values must be space delimited (e.g., STATS AUDIENCES)." But it is the "&scope=STATS" param that is optional, not all params. The example confused me.

Now my code reads

```
...

params = {  "grant_type" : "client_credentials" }

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params)

...
```

which works.